# Intersecting two list of dictionary by values of only specific keys C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries of varying lengths. The keys in both the dictionary are identical and the values may not be.

```
var A = List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
var B = List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

I would like to intersect A and B abased on the values of 3 keys in the in the dictionary object contained in them.

For eg:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",val1},{"X",val2},{"Y",val3},{"Z",val4}}
```

Dictionary similar to above is contained in the list A and B with varying values for val1,val2,val3,val4. I want to intersect A and B if values for keys W,X,Y are equal but I dont care about the value in Z for intersection. Is there a way to achieve this elegantly?

Elaborating with an example:

```
   A.add(new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",123},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",103}});
   A.add(new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",124},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",893}});
   A.add(new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",123},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",134}});

   B.add(new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",123},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",900}});
   B.add(new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",124},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",893}});
   B.add(new Dictionary<string,object>{{"W",212},{"X",321},{"Y",789},{"Z",134}});
```

If I do A.intersect(B), I would like to get the following list back,

```
{"W",123},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",103}
{"W",123},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",900}
{"W",124},{"X",456},{"Y",789},{"Z",893}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you give an example of what the desired result would be in this case?

Comment: Wait what? You have two Lists of Dictionaries?

Comment: What do you mean by intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you an IEnumerable:

```
var c=A.Select(a=>new {W=a[W],X=a[X],Y=a[Y]})
  .Intersect(B.Select(a=>new {W=a[W],X=a[X],Y=a[Y]}));
```

Alternatively, create yourself a custom IEqualityComparer, and then you can do this:

```
var c=A.Intersect(B,new MyComparer());
```

something like:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string,object>>
{
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string,object> b1, Dictionary<string,object> b2)
    {
        if (b2 == null && b1 == null)
           return true;
        else if (b1 == null || b2 == null)
           return false;
        else if(b1["W"]==b2["W"] && b1["X"]==b2["X"] && b1["X"]==b2["X"])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string,object> bx)
    {
        int hCode = bx["W"] ^ bx["X"] ^ bx["Y"];
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor modifications might be needed to get the hashcode from bx["W"] etc since it's an object.  W,X,Y should be quoted in the first example if they are indeed strings and not just placeholder property names.

Comment: works fine, just a quick follow up. Will this work if I want same behavior but like a set subtraction using except?

Comment: Yes.  But if you are doing both, I'd really suggest using the IEqualityComparer, or creating a custom type that inherits from Dictionary<string,object> so you can implement the interfaces needed directly.  Then you wouldn't even need to supply an IEqualityComparer at all and just let the defaults work.